# TypeScript/Angular: Cannot find name 'XXX'

Tags: function, angular, typescript, components

[image]

I have two functions in the same TypeScript component. When I try to call one already declared, VSCode reports that it "[ts] Cannot find name 'XXX'.".

---

As requested by [Tiep Phan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3676586/tiep-phan), this is the full code:

```
liveSearchFMs(input: any) {
  this._ectmService.getFMsFromUserSearch(input).subscribe(
    fanmissions => this.fanmissions = fanmissions,
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
  );
}

timeout(input) {
  var enteredValue = input;
  var timeout = null;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    this.liveSearchFMs(enteredValue);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: show your code without tooltip

Comment: use arrow function or store context as my answer below will fix your problem

Comment: I keep seeing this and it makes no sense: `error => this.errorMessage = <any>error`. Why the type assertion? Do people just imitate Ward Bell even when he is wrong?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Eh.. Ward Bell? What's that? Can you give more details? `error => this.errorMessage = <any>error` is used when my HTTP service returns an error.

Comment: I am talking about the type assertion `<any>error`. It is absurd. Error is already declared as being of type `any`. I see people writing this all over the place.  Ward Bell writes the angular 2/4 docs. He is a very nice, mannered and well intentioned individual but his TypeScript is ranges from mediocre to poor.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I just copied this piece of code from so many tutorials found on Internet. Do you think it is useless? Can you explain?

Comment: I mean you can just write `error => this.errorMessage = error` because it is already of a compatible type. Type assertions are dangerous anyway, but here it is also  redundant. Anyway what I am getting at is indeed copy and paste. I just find it strange. And I have to maintain code that gets written like that

Comment: @AluanHaddad Well thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you wanna create something like this

```
export class EctmListComponent implements OnInit {
    // other code
    private timeoutTracker;

    timeout(input) {
        if (this.timeoutTracker) {
            clearTimeout(this.timeoutTracker);
        }
        //use arrow function instead
        this.timeoutTracker = setTimeout(() => {
            this.liveSearchFMs(input);
        }, 1000);
        // or store context first
        /*
        const ctx = this;
        this.timeoutTracker = setTimeout(function() {
            ctx.liveSearchFMs(input);
        }, 1000);
        */
        // or using bind method
        /*
        this.timeoutTracker = setTimeout((function() {
            this.liveSearchFMs(input);
        }).bind(this), 1000);
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution Tiep. Thanks. It works. But just one thing: You have to change `clearTimeout(timeoutTracker);` by `clearTimeout(this.timeoutTracker);`.

Comment: Just for clarity : By calling setTimeout without arrow function, you didn't pass the context of the object to the closure. It means that `this` in your function doesn't refer to the EctmListComponent. By using an arrow function, you define the context inside the closure and `this` correctly refers to the object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this keyword. so this.liveSearchFMs

Comment: That doesn't work. I added it to the respective function. VSCode accepted it but when I call **timeout($event)** with a (keyup) event, the browser reports that _this.liveSearchFMs is not a function_. Ref. https://image.ibb.co/cgibQk/thisxxxnotafunction.png